# If I applied a German student visa from the U.K., can another embassy issue the visa when it is granted?

Tags: germany, student-visa, passport

I am a Turkish national, and I am applying for a long-term (D-type) German student visa from U.K. However, I will not be in the U.K. by the time the visa is (hopefully) granted.

So, **in such a case, can another embassy issue the visa when it is granted? Has anybody done such a thing before?**

In my understanding, if the German government accepts my visa application, the process of issuing the visa document to my password should be done by any authorized embassy.

Comment: Have you asked this question of the German embassy or consulate where you have or will apply?

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica I have asked, but didn't get clear yes/no answer, so I wanted to ask to you guys whether anyone has done it, or knows whether it could happen or not.